# Java cant edit thread stopwatch timeout

Tags: java, multithreading

Hey I created this code for timeout in my tcp communication, but after I run thread, I can't change the end time? any ideas?

```java
public class Timer extends Thread{
    ThreadLocal<Long> endTime= new ThreadLocal<>() {
        @Override
        public Long initialValue() {
            return System.currentTimeMillis()+1000;
        }
    };

    private Client client;

    public void resetTimer(){
        endTime.set((System.currentTimeMillis())+1000);
    }

    Timer(Client client){
        this.client=client;
        endTime.set(System.currentTimeMillis()+1000);
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (endTime.get()<System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                client.endTimeout();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Well I can, but in the actual if the value stays initial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ThreadLocal<Long> endTime` completely defeats the purpose of your value. Each thread has it's own value. So your start your "Timer" in that run loop there is `endTime.get()` which returns the value for your timer thread.

If from another thread you call `endTime.set(...)` it will set the value for **the other thread** that you call the method from. Not your Timer thread.

Maybe you want an [AtomicLong](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html);